# Git clone not cloning dotfiles

Tags: linux, git, github

The files are visible on my repository, and yet when I do `git clone gitrepo` they don't appear on my disk. What causes that?

Comment: Do they show up with `ls -a`?

Comment: they could be in your directory but not necessarily in git repository. does `git ls-files` in the original repo show them?

Comment: What do you mean by *visible on my repository* here? A repository holds *commits*, not files; how are you viewing the repository and its commits?